# How can I rename Publish Profile in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017, one-click-web-publishing

In Visual Studio 2017 when you create a custom Publish Profile, you don't have an option to set name of the profile and it creates profiles with default names like `CustomProfile` and `CustomProfile1` and show them in *Publish* toolbar like this:

[image]

In previous versions of Visual Studio, when you create a publish profile, there is a dialog asking for profile name. How can I rename publish profile in Visual Studio 2017?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Visual Studio 2017 Version >= 15.3

In Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.3 you can rename the publish profile. Here are steps to rename a publish profile:

1. Click on *Edit Publish Profile* button (gear icon [image]) on *Publish* toolbar.
2. In the Publish page, from the drop-down that contains profiles, choose the profile that you want to rename.
3. In the *Summary* section OR Under the *Actions* dropdown ([image]) , Click *Rename profile...* link.
4. In the *Rename Profile* window, enter the new name and click *Save* button.

The profile name will be changed immediately and if you open the drop-down menu, you will see the new name for the profile.

> If you are using a version lower than 15.3, then you can upgrade to 15.3 or
>   read the next part of the answer.

**Workaround for Visual Studio 2017 Version < 15.3**

Publish profiles are `.pubxml` files and Visual Studio 2017 shows a list of file names in *Publish* toolbar. 
To change name of publish profile, you should change file name and then unload and reload project.

[image]

Here are the steps to rename publish profile:

1. Go to *Solution Explorer* → *Project* → *Properties* → *PublishProfiles*
2. Choose the file which you want to rename it and rename it.
3. Right click on Project and choose *Unload Project*
4. Right click on Project and choose *Reload Project*

Answer (score 9):

When publishing a console app, the option is a bit hidden away:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you can't find the PublishProfiles folder, in my web project (VS 2017 / 15.2) it is under *My Project -> PublishProfiles*.

Just open a file explorer window onto it and rename the offending item.

Answer (score 0):

This is not answering the question but may be an important node when renaming. In my case (VS 2022 17.5.2), after renaming the profile to something containing an **underscore** (e. g. "otp_test"), the new name is being shown with a **double underscore** and has to be used with double underscore like so:

MSBuild.exe mysolution.sln /p:PublishProfile=**otp__test**

which seems very weird to me.

The profile names in the combo box dropdown (only the drop down part of the combobox) are being shown correctly however.

[image]